# Cannot resize LinearLayout in height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

I have a `LinearLayout` inside of a `Scrollview`. After doing some animations, there is blank space at the bottom when I scroll down. So I want to resize the `LinearLayout` using this code

```
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = _linearLayoutMainWrapper.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = 100;
                _linearLayoutMainWrapper.setLayoutParams(params);
```

It doesnt work though, just nothing is happening. When I try to resize the `width` it is working though.

**The XML is**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewMain">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dip"
        android:paddingRight="16dip"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMainWrapper">

        <!-- a lot of stuff -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you show your "_linearLayoutMainWrapper" xml layout . sometimes the error lies in attributes , for instance in some cases , setting the height to wrap_content will prevent you from changing height later.

Comment: Why you not use android:layout_height="wrap_content"  on your LinearLayout? Your layout always get height from scrollview. Maybe try edit height of scrollview or change linearlayout height property to wrap_content.

Comment: I did, it didnt work, so I changed it, because the comment above says that "wrap_content" can cause problems. It still doesnt work though.

Comment: give the layout height some constant value and check again . it might help out since the value won't be dependent on any other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some margin setted for this view ? Try to clear in params margins and the `height` for LinearLayout should be `youScrollView.getMeasuredHeight()`.

Comment: Which view do you mean? The one I was performing animations on? It is one of many views, I hide by translating it upwards "under another view"
Thanks for the tip with the .getMeasuredHeight() though

Comment: That 'view' maybe be either LinearLayout - margin or ScrollView - padding. What animations are you performing ?